# Are you a root?

Tags: sudo, dpkg, root, lock

If I want to install a program by:

`sudo apt-get install package_name`

I always get the error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (2 No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg) , are you root?
```

I am root, but still get the error. Any idea ?

Comment: Is `sudo apt-get clean` working ? Try after logout and back login.

Comment: ls:cannot access sudo  :no such file or directory
ls:cannot access apt-get :no such file or directory
ls:cannot access clean :no such file or directory

Comment: That was `Is`, not `ls`. The command that @Pandya suggested was `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: Is command not found , sudo apt-get clean (E:Lists directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing )

Answer (score 1):

Start a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard, copy this following to Terminal window

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

Or for more detail you can read [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2011-June/246473.html)

Comment: cp: cannot stat '/var/backups/dpkg.status.0': No such file or directory - but still get the eror

Comment: @user278122 see my edit

Comment: i was reinstaled dpkg but still get the error (could open lock file bla bla)